# GeoCoordinate.Location.Speed problem

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I've got a problem with WP7 location service. U am trying to obtain gps data, such as Lattitude, Longitude and Speed. With first 2 everything is fine, but I can't get speed value. I have set "MovementThreshold" to "0" and "GeoPositionAccuracy" to "High". The value that I am getting from it all the time is NaN. Who knows how this problem could be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WP7 simply need more data points.

Reference: http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/65582/402226.aspx#402226